# jssor multiple instances - change the slide of second jssor instance on $EVT_POSITION_CHANGE event of the first jssor instance

Tags: jssor

Can anyone/jssor support help me how to change the images of second and third jssor sliders when slide show position change event trigger from the first jssor slider? I would be so much appreciated.

thanks,
c

this jssor_slider2.$GoTo(1); is not working.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
function OnSlidePositionChange(slideIndex, fromIndex) {
    var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$('slider2_container', { $AutoPlay: false });
    if (slideIndex == 3)
        jssor_slider2.$GoTo(1);
    else 
        jssor_slider2.$GoTo(slideIndex + 1);
}
jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_POSITION_CHANGE, OnSlidePositionChange);
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
&lt;script>
jssor_slider1_starter("slider1_container");

jssor_slider2_starter("slider2_container");

jssor_slider3_starter("slider3_container");
&lt;/script>

script.js file

jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {
    var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, {
...
}

function OnSlidePositionChange(slideIndex, fromIndex) {

//HELP ME PLEASE HERE.....

        //var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$('slider2_container', {});
        //if (slideIndex == 3)
        //    nestedSliders[1].$GoTo(1);
        //else 
        //    nestedSliders[1].$GoTo(slideIndex + 1);
    }
    jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_POSITION_CHANGE, OnSlidePositionChange);


}


jssor_slider2_starter = function (containerId) {
    var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, {
......
}
}

jssor_slider3_starter = function (containerId) {
    var jssor_slider3 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, {
......
}
}
```

Comment: You have 3 sliders in your page. And one of them is a nested slider which maintains several child sliders. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

$JssorSlider$.$EVT_POSITION_CHANGE fires continuously while sliding.
$JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK fires while slide change.

Please do this job this way,

```
function jssor_slider3_starter(containerId_1, containerId_2, containerId_3)
{
    var options1 = {};
    var options2 = {};
    var options3 = {};
    ...
    var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId_1, options1);
    var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId_2, options2);
    var jssor_slider3 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId_3, options3);
    ...

    function OnSlidePark(slideIndex, fromIndex) {
        if (slideIndex == 3)
            jssor_slider2.$GoTo(1);
        else 
            jssor_slider2.$GoTo(slideIndex + 1);
    }
    jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, OnSlidePark);
    ...
}
```